# Missing value when building a grid of ggplot plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to build a grid. Here is the code that I've tried:

```
     install.packages("gridExtra")
     library(gridExtra)
     p1 <- ggplot(aes(x = friend_count), data = pf) + geom_histogram()
     p2 <- p1 + scale_x_log10()
     p3 <- p1 + scale_x_sqrt()
     grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,ncol = 1)
```

When I run this I get the following error:

`Error in if (is.waive(data) || empty(data)) return(cbind(data, PANEL = integer(0))) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide your data frame, and it turns out that makes the problem perfectly reproducible:

```
ggplot(aes(x = friend_count), data = pf) + geom_histogram()
# Error in if (empty(data)) return(cbind(data, PANEL = factor())) : 
# missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Now with data frame:

```
pf <- data.frame(friend_count = rpois(1000, 10))
ggplot(aes(x = friend_count), data = pf) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

Maybe you meant to write `data = df` instead of `data = pf`? In base R, `pf` is a function, and the error you get occurs when one provides a function in place of data:

```
ggplot(function() {}, aes(x)) + geom_histogram()
# Error in if (empty(data)) return(cbind(data, PANEL = factor())) : 
# missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

In either case, this has nothing to do with `gridExtra` or `grid.arrange`.